# Autopostback a page in Page_Unload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to autopost a page in Page_Unload. When I write `Response.Redirect`, I got error.

Want to achieve show Data List. I'm databinding it, but it shows after refreshing the page.

Can somebody help me?

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ... 
  DataList1.DataBind();
 //autopostback in this line
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't doing so create an endless loop? (Leaving a page forcing the user to re-post to the page) (Exception being if `Page_Load` triggered a redirect)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you define "autopost"?  Are you trying to redirect the user to an external POST request?  Are you trying to POST to an external resource on without redirecting the user's browser?  Are you trying to direct the user to a resource within your own application?  (In that last case, why go through a POST when you're already in code?  Just call the code you need to call from there.)

Comment: `"When I write Response.Redirect, i got error."` - And the error is?...

Comment: `Page_Unload` is a serverside event(the last). [**Have a look**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx#lifecycle_events). So it is odd to "postback" if you are still at the server. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @David "Response is not available in this context."

Comment: @Darren i want to achieve show DataList

Comment: @Özkan: Without more informations: call your method `ShowDataList()`. Your problem seems to be that you are not reloading the datasource of the `DataList`(i'm guessing).

Comment: @Özkan: Makes sense, `Page_Unload` is after the response has been sent to the client.  So the response can't be modified at that point.  When you say "show DataList" can you describe the structure of what you're doing a bit more?  Maybe show more complete code?  Why do you need to post anything?  If you want to direct the user to another page, do so in the response (not after it).  If you want to show data on the current page, again, do so in the response.  It's really not clear what you're trying to do, but it is clear that you're _probably_ going about it all wrong from the start.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I'm already called and bind it. But DataList's rows shows after refreshing the page.

Comment: @Özkan: When did you call to bind it?  It's not in the code you've shown us, so we can't assume anything about it.  You're talking about server-side code.  The page is "mid-refresh" at this time.  You can bind your data during this time (but not in `Page_Unload` as that's after the response has left the server).

Comment: @David I understand all you said. I've a usercontrol in the page. This usercontrol is a popup. In this popup, I'm taking cityName and take it a session variable. When i got this value, I want to bind my DataList. I do this in Page_Unload.. Because works queue is page_load, usercontrol_pageload

Comment: The last place to do anything that will affect the response produced by the form is in `PreRender`.

Comment: @Özkan: I'm sorry, but it really sounds like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how WebForms works.  You're going to need to work on that, and it's a lot more than can be fixed in a single Stack Overflow question.  To be specific, you can't bind anything in `Page_Unload` because that event happens _after_ the response has been sent to the client.  You need to bind your data during the processing of the response.  This commonly gets triggered either from `Page_Load` or from an event handler for a specific control on the page (such as a button click, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything like that in the `Unload` event.

Whe the `Unload` event happens, the page has already been rendered and sent to the browser, so it's too late to do anything to change the response.

Besides, making a postback from server code doesn't make sense, as that would simply create an eternal loop without anything ever being sent back to the browser. If you want to make a postback when something happens in the browser, you would do that using Javascript, not in the server code.

Answer (score 0):

use the **PreRender** event instead of **UnLoad**.
Note: I know its old question but I believe some one would get use of this answer.